# How to create Database Login and User for Windows Service Virtual Account in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I'm trying to create a SQL Server login for a Windows service virtual account, but the straightforward approach does not work.

```
CREATE LOGIN [NT Service\ServiceName] FROM WINDOWS
```

> Windows NT user or group 'NT Service\ServiceName' not found. Check the name again.

Installers can obviously do it. SQL Server does it for SqlAgent and SSRS. What's the correct SQL query for this?

Comment: this doesn't qualify as an answer, but it might help - A NT SERVICE virtual user is local to host computer.  So a service running on some system which isn't the database server won't be able to connect to the database server using the NT SERVICE account, and you won't be able to create a NT SERVICE sql login for a service running on any other than the database server itself.  The alternatives would be a domain account, a "standard" sql login, or possibly password-synced local accounts (on the two servers).